# Why the "graph" in GraphQL?

Tags: graph, graphql

Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't know why GraphQL has *graph* in the title.

I'm guessing it is something to do with [Graph Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28abstract_data_type%29) and [graph](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/graph/info) and can see some sort of connection but it would be great if someone can explain it in simple terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL's logo is definately a graph theoretical graph. I think it's because the data it's meant to fetch is graph theoretical in nature. It was developed by Facebook for their needs, and FB is has a large social network (aka a graph). If you look at the description [here](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1691455094417024/graphql-a-data-query-language/), they mention it works well with "graph-structured data stores", and that they think of data in terms of "a graph of objects".